# git remote update failed. But success after change remotes order

Tags: git

Before today the server is working properly. 
But today I call

> git remote update

The error message shows

```
Fetching A
Fetching B
fatal: internal server error
remote: internal server error 
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
error: Could not fetch B
```

The strange thing is that I can update B success after I remove A remote first. Then I add B remote back and call update again. Two server update success.

I can report this situation everytime. The main repository is on A

1. Init Aserver repo
2. Sync project
3. Add B remote
4. call "git remote update"

I have no clue how this happened and I'm appreciate if someone can tell me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The failure strongly suggests that the repository on server B is corrupt.

The fact that it works when you don't update `A` first suggests that updating `A` drops some `remote/A` references that are keeping good copies of the commits in the local repository.  By avoiding that, you keep good copies of the commit(s) that you would have to receive from B, so that when you ask B about its commits, your Git says: *ah, I already have these commits* and therefore your Git does not ask B's Git for those commits.  If the theoretical (not yet proven, but likely) corruption on B affects just *those* commits, then avoiding asking for those commits avoids demonstrating the existence of the corruption.

If the repository on B *is* corrupt—which you can test by logging on to the B server and using `git fsck` on the repository in question—then you should replace it with a good copy found elsewhere, if possible.